# How to filter through a FormArray using Pipe in Angular to search for specific value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-filters, pipes-filters

I have a following object as formArray that I am passing inside of the transform method in my pipe.ts file. The object looks as following

[image]

I want to access the value property of said object, where the firstName and lastName are stored. I want to filter it by those first and last name to search for a specific user inside of that FormArray

[image]

I have the following in my pipe ts file, which is referenced in the html file displaying those names and email address.

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(nameData: FormArray, searchData:string) : FormArray{


    if(searchData === ""){
      return nameData;
  }
    var arrayForms = nameData.value;
    for(var element of arrayForms){
      if(element.valid){
        return arrayForms.filter((arrayForm)=> {
          return arrayForm.value.firstName.includes(searchData);
        })
      }
    }   
 }
```

at first I tried just using .filters to filter through, but I get error saying filter is not available for FormArray, so I tried converting the formArray into a regular array, but doing that, when debugging my nameData.value comes up as invalid, making the whole code block useless. I was expecting the filter to at first filter through the firstName property of the array

Answer (score 0):

The FormArray type has a controls property on it which is of type `AbstractControl[]`. You should be able to utilize that to look into the values you want and filter accordingly. Something as follows.

```
nameData.controls.filter(control => control.valid && control.value.firstName.includes(searchData));
```

Its hard to give a full answer based on the limited information you gave above. If this code doesn't work exactly for you, providing an MVP in a StackBlitz example would help you solve your exact problem.

Comment: I see, thanks for responding, ya seems like the nameData.control is returning invalid when I just highlight that portion on the chrome console so don't think this might work, also I was doing return nameData.controls.filter and seems like I can't return that either. I'll try and make a stackBlitz and post it. Thanks anyways